# How to get KeePass running on Mac?

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan, keepass, mono-framework

I've searched around, and so far I haven't found any helpful information, so I decided to ask here!

I am running Mac OS X 10.11.1, I have downloaded and installed Mono 4.2.1, and I am trying to run KeePass 2.31. I tried following the instructions [here](http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html), but when I try to run `mono Keepass.exe`, KeePass tries to open, but quits and reports the following error messages:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.get_SmallIconSize () <0x6e94698 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.get_SmallIconSize () <0x6e94660 + 0x0001d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_SmallIconSize () <0x6e94628 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.UpdateUIState (Boolean bSetModified, System.Windows.Forms.Control cOptFocus) <0x6e90f80 + 0x003bb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.UpdateUIState (Boolean bSetModified) <0x6e90f58 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.OnFormLoad (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) <0x6e2ee20 + 0x02f4b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) <0x6e2e5d8 + 0x00062> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) <0x6e2e3a0 + 0x00080> in <filename unknown>:0
```

[According to Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/getting-started-guide/), "Windows.Forms is part of a standard Mono installation." I'm not sure where to go from here now, since I downloaded the latest version of Mono and none of the documents/guides are helping. I would appreciate your help! Thanks.

UPDATE:

As suggested in the comments, I've updated XQuartz and now when I run `mono KeePass.exe`, I get the following errors:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUICarbon.get_SmallIconSize () <0x702b118 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.get_SmallIconSize () <0x702b0e0 + 0x0001d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_SmallIconSize () <0x702b0a8 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.UpdateUIState (Boolean bSetModified, System.Windows.Forms.Control cOptFocus) <0x70073f8 + 0x003bb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.UpdateUIState (Boolean bSetModified) <0x70073d0 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at KeePass.Forms.MainForm.OnFormLoad (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) <0x6fba000 + 0x02f4b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) <0x6f186a0 + 0x00062> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) <0x6f18468 + 0x00080> in <filename unknown>:0 

Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (Status status) <0x57e9d58 + 0x0016b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Drawing.StringFormat.set_Alignment (StringAlignment value) <0x57eaa48 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.StringFormat:set_Alignment (System.Drawing.StringAlignment)
  at System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader.CalcColumnHeader () <0x6ff2280 + 0x00093> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader:CalcColumnHeader ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.LayoutHeader () <0x6effa58 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.LayoutDetails () <0x6eff478 + 0x0007b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.CalculateListView (ListViewAlignment align) <0x6efd1c8 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.Redraw (Boolean recalculate) <0x6efd150 + 0x0004f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListView_SizeChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) <0x6efd120 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged (System.EventArgs e) <0x6830a28 + 0x0006f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 clientWidth, Int32 clientHeight) <0x6830590 + 0x001e8> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height) <0x683bfc8 + 0x000e3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCoreInternal (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x683bb38 + 0x0034b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x683baf8 + 0x00036> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsInternal (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x68361c0 + 0x001ae> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:SetBoundsInternal (int,int,int,int,System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.LayoutDockedChildren (System.Windows.Forms.Control parent, System.Windows.Forms.Control[] controls) <0x68314b0 + 0x00467> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.Layout (System.Object container, System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs args) <0x6831230 + 0x000cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent) <0x6830fe8 + 0x00128> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent) <0x6847de0 + 0x0004b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout (System.Windows.Forms.Control affectedControl, System.String affectedProperty) <0x6830bb8 + 0x0022b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout () <0x6840ff8 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout (Boolean performLayout) <0x68411d0 + 0x002a7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout () <0x68411b0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:ResumeLayout ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.UpdateLayout () <0x69df630 + 0x00ba3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs e) <0x69df5e8 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout (System.Windows.Forms.Control affectedControl, System.String affectedProperty) <0x6830bb8 + 0x0022b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResizeInternal (System.EventArgs e) <0x6830b28 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize (System.EventArgs e) <0x6830b08 + 0x0001a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged (System.EventArgs e) <0x6830a28 + 0x00025> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 clientWidth, Int32 clientHeight) <0x6830590 + 0x001e8> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height) <0x683bfc8 + 0x000e3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCoreInternal (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x683bb38 + 0x0034b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x683baf8 + 0x00036> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.SetBoundsCore (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x6a10c88 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsInternal (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x68361c0 + 0x001ae> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:SetBoundsInternal (int,int,int,int,System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.LayoutDockedChildren (System.Windows.Forms.Control parent, System.Windows.Forms.Control[] controls) <0x68314b0 + 0x00467> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.Layout (System.Object container, System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs args) <0x6831230 + 0x000cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent) <0x6830fe8 + 0x00128> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent) <0x6847de0 + 0x0004b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout (System.Windows.Forms.Control affectedControl, System.String affectedProperty) <0x6830bb8 + 0x0022b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout () <0x6840ff8 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout (Boolean performLayout) <0x68411d0 + 0x002a7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ResumeLayout () <0x68411b0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:ResumeLayout ()
  at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.UpdateLayout () <0x69df630 + 0x00b93> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs e) <0x69df5e8 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout (System.Windows.Forms.Control affectedControl, System.String affectedProperty) <0x6830bb8 + 0x0022b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResizeInternal (System.EventArgs e) <0x6830b28 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize (System.EventArgs e) <0x6830b08 + 0x0001a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged (System.EventArgs e) <0x6830a28 + 0x00025> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 clientWidth, Int32 clientHeight) <0x6830590 + 0x001e8> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height) <0x683bfc8 + 0x000e3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCoreInternal (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x683bb38 + 0x0034b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsCore (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x683baf8 + 0x00036> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.SetBoundsCore (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x6a10c88 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetBoundsInternal (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, BoundsSpecified specified) <0x68361c0 + 0x000da> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:SetBoundsInternal (int,int,int,int,System.Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.LayoutDockedChildren (System.Windows.Forms.Control parent, System.Windows.Forms.Control[] controls) <0x68314b0 + 0x00467> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout.Layout (System.Object container, System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs args) <0x6831230 + 0x000cb> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent) <0x6830fe8 + 0x00128> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent) <0x6847de0 + 0x0004b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs e) <0x69e02c8 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLayout (System.Windows.Forms.LayoutEventArgs levent) <0x6f06de0 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout (System.Windows.Forms.Control affectedControl, System.String affectedProperty) <0x6830bb8 + 0x0022b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:PerformLayout (System.Windows.Forms.Control,string)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlCollection.Remove (System.Windows.Forms.Control value) <0x6ff35e8 + 0x00067> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form+ControlCollection.Remove (System.Windows.Forms.Control value) <0x7069830 + 0x00113> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.RemoveOwnedForm (System.Windows.Forms.Form ownedForm) <0x7069808 + 0x00020> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Form:RemoveOwnedForm (System.Windows.Forms.Form)
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Owner (System.Windows.Forms.Form value) <0x702ec50 + 0x00037> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose (Boolean disposing) <0x702e968 + 0x0012f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize () <0x6a0d5d8 + 0x00018> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Going by http://keepass.info/%0D/download/p_macosx/index.html:  Did you also install XQuartz?   Have you tried the v2.23 listed there?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I did have XQuartz, but I just downloaded and installed the latest version to be sure. Now when I run `mono KeePass.exe` it opens up mono (I can see it as an application when I command-tab), but nothing is there. This time it took a lot longer to crash and reported many more errors (see the updated question). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I regularly use KeePass under mono on MacOS. I have just upgraded from KeePass 2.30 to 2.31 and found the same thing. KeePass 2.30 works correctly for me. I think we both need to bring this up in the KeePass forums.

EDIT:

The issue has already been raised in the forums, I didn't find it the first time I looked. I'm blaming the terrible search on SourceForge for that :)

The advice is to use 2.30 until 2.32 is available.

Here's the link:

http://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/7c096cfc/?limit=25#5cc3/60e2